# resizing string members in constructor

Tags: c++, string, c++11, constructor

I've to make sure the string members are of fixed size during construction. However they can increase their size after construction is done and later in the program, user chooses to add more text to it.

```
class A {
    std::string name;
    std::string desc;
    int num;

  public:
    A(int, std::string, std::string);
    .....
}
```

Now if I do this -

```
A(int n, std::string name, std::string d) : 
    num(n),
    name(name),
    desc(d) 
{
    ....
}
```

I'll have to call `resize()` inside the constructor body. This means there exists full string lengths at some time during the construction. Let's say I want the initial size to be 5, and user passes 20 chars string, during the construction and before `resize()`, the string would contain 20 chars, right?

Now I was thinking along the lines of doing this -

```
A(int n, std::string name, std::string d) : 
    num(n)
{
    name = name;
    desc = d;
    name.resize(5);
    desc.resize(5);
    ....
}
```

But this would be same right?

Should I instead call `resize()` on passed parameters itself? Or is there any better way..

Comment: why do you want to resize the strings?

Comment: How about something like `name( name.substr(0, 5) ),` ?

Comment: Practically you want to truncate the input string when the constructor is called and copy into the variable member?

Comment: I think you mean something like `reserve`?

Comment: @tobi303 so if user enters 20 char string, I just want 5 chars initially.

Comment: You'd want to *move* those anyway, then resize, thereby making "which one" somewhat irrelevant.

Comment: @BiagioFesta yes.

Comment: @Rakete1111 `reserve` is totally different thing. I am not reserving for future, but cutting down size at the moment.

Comment: @WhozCraig I couldn't understand what you told. Could you please explain it a little bit :/

Comment: In *this* case the end result might be the same, but how you arrive to that "sameness" is very different. In the first case you are doing *initialization* and the strings copy- (or move-) constructor is called. In the second case you are doing *assignment* and the strings copy-assignment operator is called. For strings the end result is the same, but for other classes the copy- (or move-) constructor and assignment operators might do very different things.

Comment: Also, if the strings are moved in the constructor initializer list, then the arguments should be empty once inside the constructor body. Another difference between the two variants.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg then what would be the best approach here. Move and then cut the variables, ignoring empty params OR what the highest voted answer suggests atm.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg also are strings guranteed to be moved vs the old making copy process.

Comment: That's sounds like a bad idea: sooner or later someone will call your constructor assuming that the strings passed as argument are used in your object (and if they are shorter the threshold it will be right). Your code is make it easy for the users of your code to make mistakes.

Comment: @callmeSteve I'm telling users to pass less than 5 chars at time of constructor. The question is - what if they don't.

Comment: @hg_git I would then force a std::array of 5 char (or something similar if you don't have c++11), so that your user can not easily do a mistake.

Comment: @callmeSteve I would've taken char[5] if that was possible. I just need to limit the number of chars at constructor initialization. The user might increase them afterwards.

Comment: @hg_git then provide char[5] for the constructor, and provide a string parameter for the update method. Then the parameters will match your intention at construction time and update time.

Comment: @callmeSteve the api demands `std::string` otherwise users would've to send `.c_str()` while I'd have to change it to `const char *` which might be doable or wait for c++17 when `.data()` is available.

Comment: Ok, from your question I thought that you were the one designing the api. which is why I commented (and not answered) that "asking for a string when really what is required are 5 char" does not sounds like a good plan. Now if everyone is happy doing it then there is an upvoted solution for that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What about constructor like this:

```
A::A(int n, const std::string &name, const std::string &d) :
    n(n), name(name, 0, 5), d(d, 0, 5)
{
}
```

The strings are never copied in their full length. They are taken by reference and the copy is constructed using at most first 5 characters.

It uses the [substring constructor](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/string) (number 3).

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like the following

```
class A 
{
private:    
    int num;
    std::string name;
    std::string desc;
    static const size_t INITIAL_SIZE = 5;
public:
    A( int num, const std::string &name, const std::string &desc )
        : num( num ), 
          name( name.substr( 0, INITIAL_SIZE ) ), 
          desc( desc.substr( 0, INITIAL_SIZE ) )
    {
        //
    }       
};
```